# Order of integration.

Tags: integration

$$ \int^1_{\frac{1}{4}} dx \int^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}_1  \frac{\sin \frac{1}{y}}{4-y^2} dy$$
I do not know how can you change the order of integration. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{cases}\frac14\le x\le1\\{}\\1\le y\le\frac1{\sqrt x}\end{cases}\;\;\implies\;\;\begin{cases}1\le y\le 2\\{}\\\frac14\le x\le\frac1{y^2}\end{cases}$$

Comment: ok, that's true. What about function? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user180834 What about it?

Comment: I see that it will be $\int^2_1 dy \int^{y^{-2}}_{\frac{1}{4}} f(x,y)$
And give me $f(x,y)$

Comment: @user180834 I cannot give you that: you **already** have a function there!

Comment: I know. But we change order of integration and the function is a bit another.

Comment: @user180834 No, it is not *a bit another*: it is exactly the same. You're changing the order of integration, not doing a change of *variables*

Comment: ok, so help me and show how to integrate it.